# Nameless areas in Windows EXE memory map?

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly, linker

I have pasted below a screenshot of a memory map generated by OllyDbg of a Windows EXE I linked myself (ie, manually created all the PE/COFF headers and field values). The EXE was created to have no imports. I have a question about the memory map:

What is the nameless Map type area at 0x7F6F0000 ? I did not specify any such area in my headers. Also, what are the nameless areas at 70000, 80000, C0000, and D0000?

[image: Memory map of minimal exe]

One reason I want to know this is to determine whether it is ok for me to free these areas to make more contiguous memory available to my application, and to simpify my memory map.

Comment: This is not one question, but a platoon, and they amount to a request for a tutorial on PE files. I don't think this is going to fly.

Comment: I edited the questions to focus on the most important one.

Comment: The first rule of PE format debugging is you don't ask about PE format debugging on SO.  The second rule about PE format debugging is you *DO NOT* ask about PE format debugging on SO.  And no shirts, no shoes :)

Comment: Its not really a debugging question. I just want to know why the Windows loader is creating these apparently random areas of memory in my image, and what the purpose of these areas is, if any.

Comment: Since I re-edited the question and focused it I am requesting that it be reopened.

Comment: Your tool kinda sucks, get a better one: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533